# How to convert 12 hours datetime to timestamp with javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a datetime in following format `28/11/2015 09:41 PM` and I want to convert it to epoch timestamp. How can I do that with javascript?

Additionally: I want to add and substracts 7200 seconds from that timestamp and convert it back to the original format. How can I do that? Is it necessary to convert datetime to timestamp first?

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome library available for that!

http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

A great place to find information on JavaScript's built-in objects is the MDN, which has this article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on the datetime (or really just Date) object.

The way to get an epoch timestamp from a Date object is to use the getTime() function. It returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970.

```
var dateNow = Date.now();
var epochNow = dateNow.getTime();
```

You can then just add the seconds to it:

```
epochNow += (7200 * 1000); // * 1000 because it's in milliseconds
```

And then convert it back:

```
dateNow.setTime(epochNow);
```

Good luck!

**NOTE**

Beware inconsistencies in JavaScript Date implementations, especially in earlier versions of Internet Explorer. As some have noted, a good library like moment.js (http://momentjs.com/ ) is very helpful to prevent problems. However, if you are only using fully modern browsers or node, you shouldn't have as many problems.

Comment: Can't we simply use `new Date(myDateString);`? Won't JavaScript directly create the date object?

Comment: As long as the date string is in the correct format, yes. However, one has to have a good understanding of what formats are good, and there are several inconsistencies among browsers. I've found that RFC 2822 timestamps (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14) are consistent. But @Lenny said that he already had a datetime object, so he wouldn't need to create a new one.